# Angular 5 Observable and ngModel Error: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Tags: angular

I'm building a form using **[(ngModel)]="article.title"** for one of the input fields. I know I can use the safe navigation operator in string interpolation but I want to use two way data binding.

The console is showing the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
    at Object.View_EditPostComponent_0._co [as updateDirectives] (EditPostComponent.html:11)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14689)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13836)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14187)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14119)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13842)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14187)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14145)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13837)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14187)
```

The Template is:

```
<input ... [ngModel)]="article.title" ... />
```

The Component:

```
export class EditPostComponent implements OnInit {

[...]

createPostForm: FormGroup;
urlParam: any;
article: any;

[...]

ngOnInit() {
  this.urlParam = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params;

  this.blogService.getArticle(this.urlParam.id)
    .subscribe(data => {this.article = data});
}
```

Using string interpolation with the Elvis operator works fine and doesn't throw any error, but ngModel is giving the error.

Could somebody tell me why is that and suggest a solution? Thanks

Comment: It happens because you load `article` **asynchronously** by using a `Promise`, that means that article is not filled when the Component loads. The solution is to use the Elvis operator as you said, or just hide the element before the Promise completes, this can be done by using `*ngIf`.

Comment: Thanks @Syncro, I'm hiding the the form sa you suggested and now the error goes away, but I get a new one: `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'null'.`

Comment: Have you tried using ngIf? Can you reproduce your issue?

Comment: @yuzui I'm using this in the template: `<input *ngIf="article" [(ngModel)]="article.title" type="text" name="title" class="form-control">` 
 using the same code that is in the question and its throwing the error: _ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'null'._

Comment: @yuzui enableProdMode() solved the issue. Thanks